# unable to spawn git no such file or directory on a specific fork on github

Tags: git, fork, spawn

The problem is with this fork/repo :
https://github.com/RubenWillems/CCNet

I can get other forks on the same laptop, but not this one.
trying with ssh gives the same problem.

I'm suspecting a security setup issue with the fork, but I have no idea.

Any idea on how to (start) tackling this, I am quite new to git.

Comment: It works for me. Can you be a bit more specific, for instance, paste in the exact command you ran and output into your question?

Comment: ssh works now, it was a problem with my key :-(
but https is still giving errors, tried git command line, tortoisegit, and git extentions, all have the same problem.
command :
git.exe clone  --progress -v  "https://RubenWillems@github.com/RubenWillems/CCNet.git" "D:\Ontwikkeling\Code\RuWi\CCNet\dddd\CCNet"

error :
cannot spawn git: No such file or directory

Comment: seems to be on windows only, cloning on linux and mac seems to work...

Comment: git version 1.7.4.msysgit.0
version 1.7.4-preview20110204
Maybe it is also version related

Answer (score 1):

This http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5321236#5321236 workaround from JetBrains works for me perfectly.

Here are commands when JetBrains forum thread would not available (change repo name and url)

```
mkdir idea-community
git init idea-community
cd idea-community
git remote add origin http://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community
git pull
```

Note: It is because of too many Tags in clonned repo.