# Change to git as the push protocol for dotcloud

Tags: git, push, dotcloud

I have an app that uses rsync to push. To use git, I went into .dotcloud/config and changed

```
    "push_branch": null,
    "push_protocol": "rsync"
```

to

```
    "push_branch": "some_branch",
    "push_protocol": "git"
```

However, now when I try to push:

```
$ dotcloud push
==> Pushing code with git, branch some_branch from "./" to application myapp
Error: Unable to spawn git
```

What did I do wrong? I couldn't find docs to change the push protocol.

Comment: Is it a bit as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575878/unable-to-spawn-git-no-such-file-or-directory-on-a-specific-fork-on-github (ssh key issue)?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to use the git protocol is to do something like

```
dotcloud connect --git appname [--branch branchname]
```

in the directory where dotcloud.yml resides.